# How to get the object rename panel to appear via python code?

Tags: python

Did a bit of searching, and I can't seem to figure out how to get the object rename pop up (f2) to appear via python code. Renaming objects via python is obviously trivial, but I need to have user input in this case.

[image: Need to figure out how to get this to show up via python]

Answer (score 5):

This is a window manager call.  The code is

```py
bpy.ops.wm.call_panel(name="TOPBAR_PT_name")
```

To find this out, I used <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the command search and looked for "rename".  When I hovered over "rename active", a popup showed me the command:

[image: popup showing the command]

This works because I have *developer extras* and *python tooltips* enabled in Preferences.  I then searched for `bpy.ops.wm.call_panel` and found it in the manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.call_panel).

Finally I used the Python console to verify that it was the correct command and then wrote this answer.